# how to use session.commit in a filter with hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, servlets, servlet-filters

I am using Hibernate and jsp to write a blog system.
I want to use a filter to manage the session and transactions. now i write a filter:

```
public class SessionFilter implements Filter {

FilterConfig config;
SessionFactory sessionFactory;
Session session;

public void destroy() {

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    this.config=null;
    System.out.println("session Filter is destroyed.");

}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) config.getServletContext().getAttribute("sessionFactory");
    session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();


    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}

public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    this.config=config;
    System.out.println("session Filter is inited.");

}
```

}

now the result is my form fields are not saved to mysql .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the `destroy()` will only get called when the container shuts down.  If you want to do this approach then you probably need to put the `commit()` at the end of `doFilter()`

Comment: Absolutely correct. The normal pattern is to invoke commit() in the doFilter AFTER the chain.doFilter invocation. This pattern is fairly common, the struts2-hibernate module, for instance, works in this way (except with a struts interceptor instead of a filter).